# Global variables in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, global-variables

file.sh

```
variable='String test!'
sh show.sh
```

show.sh

```
echo $variable
```

How to send variables to another file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [exporting](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html#sect_03_02_03) it

```
export variable='String test!'
```

See that link, there's a great example out there (they're doing exactly what you are trying to do).